# Business Facebook page id?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm tring to find the Facebook ID for my business page to use with Open Graph. I have claimed my url so I can't see the id

when I enter:

```
graph.facebook.com/StagecoachWineTours
```

I get the response:

```
false
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

Your ID appears to be: 97122673369

I got it by visiting the following link:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=StagecoachWineTours

If it is still showing up as 'false' when you reach it you'll need to click on Get Access Token. After that a dialog will appear, click on Get Access Token once more. Once you have done this click on submit.

The reason you could not retrieve your info appears to be because you need to provide an access token on your Graph API call to fetch it. Once you do that you'll be able to get all sorts of info!